# Running into 401 error while scraping a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=NIFTY%20500 using python's request library but unable to. I am using the url and header displayed on the network tab but its giving [401] response. Could someone please point out my mistake ? Thank you !

```
In [13]: url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=NIFTY%20500"

In [14]: headers = {
    ...: "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=
    ...: 0.9",
    ...: "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    ...: "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8",
    ...: "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36 E
    ...: dg/91.0.864.64"
    ...: }

In [15]: requests.get(url, headers=headers)
Out[15]: <Response [401]>
```

Comment: It says "Resource not found". Check the URL please.

Answer (score 2):

To load the data from this site, try:

```py
import json
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0",
}

url = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=NIFTY+50"

with requests.session() as s:
    # load cookies:
    s.get("https://www.nseindia.com", headers=headers)

    data = s.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "name": "NIFTY 50",
    "advance": {
        "declines": "12",
        "advances": "38",
        "unchanged": "0"
    },
    "timestamp": "05-Jul-2021 13:43:47",
    "data": [
        {
            "priority": 1,
            "symbol": "NIFTY 50",
            "identifier": "NIFTY 50",
            "open": 15793.4,
            "dayHigh": 15833.2,
            "dayLow": 15762.05,
            "lastPrice": 15825.1,
            "previousClose": 15722.2,
            "change": 102.89999999999964,
            "pChange": 0.65,
            "ffmc": 681557737.89,
            "yearHigh": 15915.65,
            "yearLow": 10562.9,
            "totalTradedVolume": 133736133,
            "totalTradedValue": 98836934356.07,
            "lastUpdateTime": "05-Jul-2021 13:43:47",
            "nearWKH": 0.568936864030054,
            "nearWKL": -49.817758380747726,
            "perChange365d": 48.22,
            "date365dAgo": "03-Jul-2020",
            "chart365dPath": "https://static.nseindia.com/sparklines/365d/NIFTY-50.jpg",
            "date30dAgo": "04-Jun-2021",
            "perChange30d": 0.33,
            "chart30dPath": "https://static.nseindia.com/sparklines/30d/NIFTY-50.jpg",
            "chartTodayPath": "https://static.nseindia.com/sparklines/today/NIFTY-50.jpg"
        },
        {
            "priority": 0,
            "symbol": "HINDALCO",

...
```

Comment: OK. This works. Why did not my piece of code work ?

Comment: @prepmath Because to get correct response from the server you have to set right cookies.

Comment: I guess it used to work before.
now it gives 401 error

Comment: @BishwajitVikram I've tried the script now and it gives the expected output. It might be some temporary issue.