# Looping python requests causes a 401

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a pretty simple script that is trying to pull values from a website that only allows chunks of the values per call.   The 1st request works fine but subsequent requests cause a 401 error.
ind = [0,1000]

```
for ind in range:
    tgt = "https://host.example.com/rest/api/2/user/search?username=.&start-index=" + str(ind) + "&maxResults=1000"
    print(tgt)
    session = requests.Session()
    sessions = session.get(tgt, headers=headers,auth=(user, pwd))
    print (sessions.headers)
    print (sessions.cookies)
    result = sessions.json()
```

when I look at the headers the first request has an'X-AUSERNAME' but the next one fails to authenticate.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried both with re-creating the session and using the same session and I get the same result

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `sessions` is a confusing var name here, something like `response` would be clearer.  Can you show more of the code - where is the loop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252621/running-into-401-error-while-scraping-a-website

Comment: Sorry.   Fixed the missing loop information.   I probably should change my var names for clarity.

Comment: Not sure how that other question addresses mine.   The request works just fine the first time through.  It is the 2nd time through that I have the problem.

Comment: You created a request session inside the loop, which means for every request it will create a new session. you should instead create a session outside of the loop and use its context for the entire range.

Comment: I tried that initially. Same result.